# unknown file format when load the otf file using PIL.ImageFont.truetype

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

I'm loading a font file using the PIL module. But errors occurred: **unknown file format**. 
What I load is a `otf` file, and I'm using the `PIL.ImageFont.truetype` function. It should be OK, but it didn't.

I search the documentation about PLT, and I'm sure the function is right.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

fontsize = 50

font = ImageFont.truetype('./NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf', fontsize, encoding='utf-8')
```

I expect a font object, but the actual is:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-48a2319a31ba> in <module>
      9 #!del NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip
     10 
---> 11 font = ImageFont.truetype('./NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf', fontsize, encoding='utf-8')
     12 #font = ImageFont.load('NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf')

~\.conda\envs\for_kaggle\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in truetype(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    544 
    545     try:
--> 546         return freetype(font)
    547     except IOError:
    548         if not isPath(font):

~\.conda\envs\for_kaggle\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in freetype(font)
    541 
    542     def freetype(font):
--> 543         return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    544 
    545     try:

~\.conda\envs\for_kaggle\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py in __init__(self, font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
    159                     return
    160             self.font = core.getfont(
--> 161                 font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine=layout_engine
    162             )
    163         else:

OSError: unknown file format
```

Answer (score 2):

please include below lines of code before

```
----**font = ImageFont.truetype('./NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf', fontsize, encoding='utf-8')**

!wget -q --show-progress https://noto-website-2.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip

!unzip -p NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf > NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf

!rm NotoSansCJKjp-hinted.zip
```